# <IPython.core.display.HTML object> message in Jupyter/Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, html-object

**Hello, I am trying to see a graph of an exercise in Python of plots. I am in Visual Studio Code with the Jupyter extension and when I run this code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

%matplotlib notebook

#generate 4 random variables from the random, gamma, exponential, and uniform distributions

x1 = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1, 10000)
x2 = np.random.gamma(2, 1.5, 10000)
x3 = np.random.exponential(2, 10000)+7
x4 = np.random.uniform(14,20, 10000)

#plot the histograms

plt.figure(figsize=(9,3))
plt.hist(x1, density=True, bins=20, alpha=0.5)
plt.hist(x2, density=True, bins=20, alpha=0.5)
plt.hist(x3, density=True, bins=20, alpha=0.5)
plt.hist(x4, density=True, bins=20, alpha=0.5);
plt.axis([-7,21,0,0.6])

plt.text(x1.mean()-1.5, 0.5, 'x1\nNormal')
plt.text(x2.mean()-1.5, 0.5, 'x2\nGamma')
plt.text(x3.mean()-1.5, 0.5, 'x3\nExponential')
plt.text(x4.mean()-1.5, 0.5, 'x4\nUniform')
```

**The output is**

```
"<IPython.core.display.Javascript object>
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
Text(15.512406857944477, 0.5, 'x4\nUniform')"
```

I have seen that there are other queries of the same problem and they are solved changing to Jupyter (I am using it) or changing the plot here:

[</> ICON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy9pW.png)

But when I press there the only menu that pops up is the following:

[Menu "Select mimetype to render for current output"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQs1w.png)

Any clue how could I solve this?

Thank you!
Fernando.

Comment: try ```%matplotlib inline``` instead of ```%matplotlib notebook```. Is this what you are trying to get? This will get the plot to show up. Then, if you want the text output to be suppressed you can add ```plot.show()```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `%matplotlib notebook` to `%matplotlib inline` will get the plot to show up as an ouptut cell. To remove the unwanted text output, add `plt.show()` to the last line of the cell so it knows the desired output is the plot. The cell should then look like this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline

#generate 4 random variables from the random, gamma, exponential, and uniform distributions

x1 = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1, 10000)
x2 = np.random.gamma(2, 1.5, 10000)
x3 = np.random.exponential(2, 10000)+7
x4 = np.random.uniform(14,20, 10000)

#plot the histograms

plt.figure(figsize=(9,3))
plt.hist(x1, density=True, bins=20, alpha=0.5)
plt.hist(x2, density=True, bins=20, alpha=0.5)
plt.hist(x3, density=True, bins=20, alpha=0.5)
plt.hist(x4, density=True, bins=20, alpha=0.5);
plt.axis([-7,21,0,0.6])

plt.text(x1.mean()-1.5, 0.5, 'x1\nNormal')
plt.text(x2.mean()-1.5, 0.5, 'x2\nGamma')
plt.text(x3.mean()-1.5, 0.5, 'x3\nExponential')
plt.text(x4.mean()-1.5, 0.5, 'x4\nUniform')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! I tried before to use those commands separately but together they worked.
Thank you very much!